# OpenGL Shader ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error #version

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm using xcode to make a game with OpenGL. I have used GLUT to initialise a window. I have shaders that I wish to implement but when I try to compile them, I get two compile errors in the info log. My shaders look like this:

```
//FirstShader.vsh
#version 150 core

in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}

//FirstShader.fsh
#version 150 core

out vec4 fragData;

void main()
{
    fragData = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

I'm reading the file and compiling it with this code:

```
GLuint createShaderFromFile(const GLchar *path, GLenum shaderType){
GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
std::ifstream fin;
fin.open(path);
if(!fin.is_open()){
    fin.close();
    std::cout << "Shader Not Found" << std:: endl;
    return 0;
}
std::string source((std::istreambuf_iterator<GLchar>(fin)),std::istreambuf_iterator<GLchar> ());

fin.close();

const GLchar* shaderSource = source.c_str();


glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &shaderSource, NULL);

glCompileShader(shaderID);
GLint compileStatus;
glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);

if (compileStatus != GL_TRUE) {
    std::cout << "Shader failed to compile" << std::endl;
    GLint infoLoglength;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLoglength);
    GLchar* infoLog = new GLchar[infoLoglength + 1];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, infoLoglength, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << infoLog << std::endl;
    delete infoLog;
    return 0;
}


return shaderID;
}
```

Im getting these errors:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '150' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error #version
```

My OpenGL version is 2.1 and my glsl version is 1.20. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: `version '150' is not supported` is quite a clear message, don't you think? What does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` return, after you created the context?

Comment: If your GLSL Version is 1.2 then you clearly do not support version 1.5, as the error and @derhass says.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell OSX to use a newer version of OpenGL by setting it in your pixel format when you create the context. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874997/setting-up-and-using-opengl-3-0-with-mac-osx-lion10-7) of how to set it up.

Or if you're using glut, I think you want `glutInitContextVersion(x, y);` where `x` and `y` are the major and minor version numbers. GLSL 1.5 is supported in OpenGL 3.2, I think. (And you might also want `glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);`, I think.)

Comment: glutInitContextVersion(x,y); doesnt work. ive tried the context profile line of code but they both give errors.

Comment: @DavidGraovac I'm not real familiar with glut, so I'm not sure what to tell you. Have you tried setting the shader version to 1.2 and seeing what happens? I don't think there's anything in your shaders that requires 1.5 at the moment.

Comment: Note that `glutInitContextVersion()` and friends are not part of the official GLUT spec, but extensions by [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/). Don't know which GLUT version DavidGraovac is using...

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote your shaders in a way that they will actually work in GLSL 1.20.

- `in` must be replaced with `attribute` in a GLSL 1.20 vertex shader
- `out` for fragment shader output is invalid, use `gl_FragColor` or `gl_FragData [n]` instead
- Declaring a vertex attribute as `vec3` and then doing something like `vec4 (vtx, 1.0)` is completely redundant

  - If you declare the attribute as `vec4` and give it data using fewer than 4 components GLSL will automatically fill-in the attribute's missing components this way: `vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`.

#### Fragment Shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec4 position;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = position;
}
```

#### Vertex Shader:

```
#version 120

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

Of course this does not really solve your problem, because if you have a version of OS X 10.7 or newer, it supports OpenGL 3.2 and therefore GLSL 1.50 core. You need to request a core profile context for this to work, however - otherwise you will get OpenGL 2.1 and GLSL 1.20.